# ANT script error after installing newer version of JDK on my system

Tags: eclipse, ant, java-6

After installing the newer version of the JDK 6 (1.6.0_41) from 1.6.0_37, I went into Eclipse and updated the Installed JREs in the Java section under the preferences menu.  I then went into my ANT script to test some changes I made and when I tried to run the ANT script I got this error:

Specified VM install not found: type Standard VM, name jdk1.6.0_37

The specified VM is not the jdk1.6.0_41.  This has also been updated in the PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables.

Any suggestions as to WHERE else to make a change so that ANT sees this?

Here is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I don't recognise the error message. Is there logic within your build that checks the JVM version?

Comment: Thanks Mark for your question.  No there was NO logic that specifies the JVM at all.  I did find the answer to my problem though.  I posted below.  Thanks again for replying.

Comment: Ahhhh, I thought this was an ANT error. It was an Eclipse issue. +1 for posting the answer for others

Answer (score 33):

After additional hunting around in Eclipse, I found in the ANT view an External Configuration Tools option when right clicking my Ant script name and under the JRE tab is where the setting was.  I changed the setting to use the same JRE as the workspace and then all was fine.

Just in case anyone else ran into this same problem I thought it might be helpful to post my findings.

Comment: THANK YOU!
For those who might run into the same problem.
Right click on the build file in the ANT preview -> Run as -> External Tools Configurations -> JRE tab, and set it to whatever you want

Comment: I changed my configuration to "Run in the same JRE as the workspace" and hopefully this won't happen to me again.

Comment: Nice this helped

Answer (score 1):

Ant won't mind the new jdk version as long as its name stays unchanged under Preferences / Java / Installed JREs.